# Spring RestTemplate : BadRequest 400,null. while calling Get Request

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate

I am trying to call get request using `RestTemplate`. I tried like below But I am getting error `HttpClientErrorException$BadRequest: 400 null`.

Can any one tell me what I am doing wrong in calling Get Request with parameters?

```
@GetMapping("/getDepartmentInstitute")
public Integer getDeptInstByUserIDAndInstId(@RequestParam Integer nUserId,
                                            @RequestParam Integer  nDeptInst) {
return permissionsService.findDeptInstByUserIdAndInstId(nUserId,nDeptInst );        
}
```

I tried like this

```
public Integer findAlertDetails(Integer nUserId, Integer nInstId) {                 

    String uri="http://localhost:8064/spacestudy/" +instituteIdentifier +"/communication/alertmanagement/getDepartmentInstitute?nUserId="+ nUserId+"&nInstId="+nInstId+"";

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

       Integer nInstTo=restTemplate.getForObject(uri,Integer.class,nUserId,nInstId);

            System.out.println(nInstTo);    

        return nInstTo;
    }
```

Comment: For starters, you're using a nInstId parameter while your Controller expects nDeptInst.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

restTemplate.getForObject(String url, Class responseType, Object... uriVariables) is supposed to deal with uri variables like {myVar} in your String url.

If you want to set query parameters, consider using the UriComponentsBuilder.

```
URI uri = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl("http://localhost:8064/spacestudy/" +instituteIdentifier +"/communication/alertmanagement/getDepartmentInstitute")
              .queryParam("nUserId", nUserId)
              .queryParam("nDeptInst", nInstId)
              .build().toUri();

Integer nInstTo = restTemplate.getForObject(uri,Integer.class);
```

Or you can set them manually like :

```
String uri = "http://localhost:8064/spacestudy/" +instituteIdentifier +"/communication/alertmanagement/getDepartmentInstitute"
                   + "?nUserId=" + nUserId + "&nDeptInst=" + nInstId;
```

I prefer the UriComponentsBuilder solution.

Comment: Did you try to call the webservice manually with your browser ? Does it work properly ?

Comment: Actually your web service is expecting a query param nDeptInst instead of nInstId, I updated my answer accordingly. Also if the web service encounters an error, please add the stacktrace to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can build url manually as **Solution 1** or you can use UriComponentsBuilder as **Solution 2**

**Solution 1**

```
public Integer findAlertDetails(Integer nUserId, Integer nInstId) {

            String uri="http://localhost:8064/spacestudy/" +instituteIdentifier +"/communication/alertmanagement/getDepartmentInstitute?nUserId="+nUserId+"&nDeptInst="+nInstId;

            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            Integer nInstTo=restTemplate.getForObject(uri,Integer.class);

            System.out.println(nInstTo);

            return nInstTo;
        }
```

**Solution 2**

```
public Integer findAlertDetails(Integer nUserId, Integer nInstId) {
        String uri="http://localhost:8064/spacestudy/" +instituteIdentifier +"/communication/alertmanagement/getDepartmentInstitute";

        RestTemplate  restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        httpHeaders.add("Content-Type", "application/json");
        UriComponentsBuilder uriBuilder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(uri)
                .queryParam("nUserId", nUserId)
                .queryParam("nDeptInst", nInstId);

        HttpEntity<Integer> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(httpHeaders);

        ResponseEntity<Integer> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(
                uriBuilder.toUriString(),
                HttpMethod.GET,
                requestEntity,
                Integer.class
        );


        return requestEntity.getBody();
    }
```